# Pandas, Looking up header names in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract data from excel files, that really needs major reformatting, into a new simple one for easier readability. Following is a simplified example:
[image: Example]
of what I am looking at

What I am trying to do is to check if there are units rejected then look up the values with the header name and save it to a new column.

So far what I've got is

```
for each in df['Total Unit Rejected']:
    if each > 0:
        # Look up values in columns 3:7
        newDataFrame = df['Total Unit Tested','Total Unit Rejected','Notes']
```

I want the new excel sheet to look like the following image [image: Output].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please translate your images into _text_ or code that can be used to reproduce your question.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can filter to have only the rows that have `df['Total Unit Rejected'] > 0` using the following code:

```
df = df[df['Total Unit Rejected'] > 0]
```

Then you can add the `Notes` column using following code (You may need to add some logic to the lamnda function to check if the column is no NaN. It would be better to define the lambda function a separate standalone function earlier as the function body will be bigger):

```
df['Notes'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Error1']+" Error 1\n"+ x['Error2']+" Error 2\n"+x['Error3'] + " Error 3")
```

Then you can select the particular columns using the following code:

```
newDataFrame = df[['Total Unit Tested','Total Unit Rejected','Notes']]
```